# How do I remove columns from a CSV file using Scala

Tags: scala, csv, rdd

If I have a CSV like the following:

```
Id,name,number
1,sam,023
2,ron,287
```

But I wanted to make it like this while only passing the column heading as an argument, in this case "name":

```
Id,number
1,023
2,287
```

How would I do this in Scala?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share some code and explain where exactly did you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit of wrangling but the following should do it.

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines.map(_.split(",")).map(s => s(0) + " " +  s(2)).mkString("\n")
res4: String =
Id number
1 023
2 287
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
object ColDrop extends App {

  val Eol = "\n"


  def dropCol(col: String, csv: String, delim: Char = ',') = {

    def drop(line: Array[String], rmIndex: Int) = (line.take(rmIndex) ++ line.drop(rmIndex + 1)).mkString(delim.toString)

    val csvArr = csv.split(Eol)
    val header = csvArr.head.split(delim).map(_.trim)
    val rmIndex = header.indexOf(col)

    drop(header, rmIndex) + Eol + csvArr.tail.map { r =>
      drop(r.split(delim), rmIndex)
    }.mkString(Eol)
  }

  println(dropCol("name",
    """Id,name,number
      |1,sam,023
      |2,ron,287
    """.stripMargin))

}
```